# Unable to use 'getElementById' on 'span' html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and JavaScript and trying the following bit of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayTime() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("clock");
    var now = new Date();
    if(elem == null) alert("NO clock element");
    elem.innerHTML = now.toLocaleString();
    setTimeout(displayTime, 1000);
}
window.onload = displayTime();

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Digital Clock</h1>
<span id="clock"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code I am trying to implement a digital clock using span element and update the time every 1 sec.
But what I could see is `getElementById` on the span element always return null and cannot set it.
My aim is not to implement the clock but to learn JavaScript.
Please help me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It's seem there is nothing wrong with your code. [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/CQZ22/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem : `window.onload = displayTime();`

You're saving the return value of the function `displayTime` in your `window.onload`, and when the window DOES load, it runs whatever that is. But `displayTime` returns *null*. You can't run *null*.

What you're looking for is `window.onload = displayTime;`, since you want `displayTime` to run when the window does load.

And since you're immediately calling displayTime (before the window loads), the span is not yet existent.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are calling instead of assigning the `displayTime` to `onload`.

use

```
window.onload = displayTime;
```

instead of

```
window.onload = displayTime();
```

It's basically when you say `window.onload=some` it evaluates the `some` and put it's value equal to `window.onload`.

So you will say `displayTime()` it will call the function before `window` loaded, so it won't get a `span` at all.

Answer (score 0):

[Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/satibeki/1/)

Check This Jsbin file. 
i have just removed (); from window.onload = displayTime; and its working .